# change image name and store it in database with php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I working on a project with PHP Codeigniter. I want to upload an image, change the name of the image and store it in database (with extension). I have written the following code. It works perfectly but the problem is that the image name is stored without its extension in database. For example, when I run the code, the name that is stored in database is 'imagename', instead of 'imagename.jpg' or 'imagename.png'. I want to store the complete name with extension.

This is my Controller

```
public function FunctionName()
{
    $fname = ucwords($this->input->post('fname'));
    $lname = ucwords($this->input->post('lname'));
    $prof_pic = $_FILES['profile_pic']['name'];

    $config = array ('upload_path' => './images/students/',
        'allowed_types' => "jpeg|jpg|png",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'file_name' => $fname."_".$lname, 
        'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
        'file_ext_tolower' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic');

    $image_name = $config['file_name'].".".$config['file_type'];

    $data  =  array('std_fname' => $std_fname,
        'std_lname' => $std_lname,
        'profile_pic' => $image
    );
    $this->General_Model->create_record($data, "table_name");
}
```

Comment: I don't see `file_type` defined in your `$config`.

Answer (score 0):

To get uploaded file name use

```
$this->upload->data('file_name');
```

AS

```
 $this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic');
 $image_name = $this->upload->data('file_name');
```

Read **[Information about the uploaded file](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
$prof_pic = $_FILES['profile_pic']['name'];
$newName = "<Desired name>".".".pathinfo($prof_pic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$config = array ('upload_path' => './images/students/',
    'allowed_types' => "jpeg|jpg|png",
    'overwrite' => TRUE,
    'file_name' => $newName, 
    'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
    'file_ext_tolower' => TRUE
);
```

the line

```
$newName = "<Desired name>".".".pathinfo($prof_pic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Will assign the new name with the file extension of the actual file